# Come across problem in mysql when deploying website

Tags: python, mysql, ubuntu

I use ubuntu 20.04 in AWS.

I have created a python asyio webapp.

I use Nginx.

The Nginx default page could load successfully.

However, after deploying my webapp, error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/aiomysql/connection.py", line 503, in _connect
    await self._request_authentication()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/aiomysql/connection.py", line 796, in _request_authentication
    await self._process_auth(plugin_name, auth_packet)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/aiomysql/connection.py", line 819, in _process_auth
    await self.sha256_password_auth(auth_packet)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/aiomysql/connection.py", line 970, in sha256_password_auth
    pkt = await self._read_packet()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/aiomysql/connection.py", line 593, in _read_packet
    packet.check_error()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pymysql/protocol.py", line 220, in check_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 109, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'www'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 154, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(init(loop))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "app.py", line 142, in init
    yield from orm.create_pool(loop=loop, **configs.db)
  File "/home/ubuntu/srv/awesome/www/orm.py", line 17, in create_pool
    __pool = yield from aiomysql.create_pool(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/aiomysql/pool.py", line 29, in _create_pool
    await pool._fill_free_pool(False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/aiomysql/pool.py", line 167, in _fill_free_pool
    conn = await connect(echo=self._echo, loop=self._loop,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/aiomysql/connection.py", line 75, in _connect
    await conn._connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/aiomysql/connection.py", line 521, in _connect
    raise OperationalError(2003,
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1'")
```

How to fix my problem?

Comment: What does `"Access denied for user 'www'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")` tell you?

Comment: not sure about that, I did not have any password called YES